# Error in Two Process critical section solution

Tags: java, multithreading, operating-system, critical-section

I have applied two process critical section solution to two threads instead of processes. My  code is:

```
class Main
{
static boolean flag[];
static int turn;
static int count;
synchronized static void print(char ch,int n)
{
    int i;
    System.out.println(ch);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        System.out.println(i);

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
        flag = new boolean[2];
        flag[0] = flag[1] = false;
        turn = 0;
        count = 0;
        ThreadLevelOne t1 = new ThreadLevelOne('a');
        ThreadLevelTwo t2 = new ThreadLevelTwo('b');
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
}

static class ThreadLevelOne extends Thread{
    private char ch;

    public ThreadLevelOne(char ch){
        this.ch = ch;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true)
        {
            flag[0] = true;
            turn = 1;
            while(flag[1] && turn == 1);
            print(ch,3);    
            count++;
            System.out.println("Counter is : " + count);
            flag[0] = false;
        }

    }
}

static class ThreadLevelTwo extends Thread{
    private char ch;

    public ThreadLevelTwo(char ch){
        this.ch = ch;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            flag[1] = true;
            turn = 0;
            while(flag[0] && turn == 0);
            print( ch, 4);
            count++;
            System.out.println("Counter is : " + count);
            flag[1] = false;

        }

    }
}
}
```

On executing the above code, it does not run infinitely but halts at arbitrary *counter* value on each execution. Is this a valid application of the two process solution to threads? If yes, then why is program halting at arbitrary counter value? If no, then how can this be achieved in threads?

Edit after the answer of codeBlind:

output: Program execution halts at this stage
[image: Program execution halts at this stage]

Even if i dont increment the counter value, then also the program halts after a certain time

Answer (score 0):

You're a victim of concurrently executing **non-atomic operations**, specifically `count++`, as well as the way you are using flags in each thread. But for simplicity's sake, let's talk about `count++`. The `++` operator actually executes three commands, each in their own clock-cycle:

1. read value of `count`
2. add `1` to value retrieved from `count`
3. store new value into `count`

The problem you're seeing is a result of these commands being interleaved across two threads. Thread A may not have stored the new `count` value by the time that Thread B attempts to read it.

A quick fix would be to use `AtomicInteger` for count instead of primitive `int` - `AtomicInteger` guarantees thread safety for integer operations.

**EDIT**

There are other race conditions in this code as well. Each thread's while loop argument (e.g. `flag[0] && turn == 0`) is non-atomic, but both threads are capable of modifying `turn`. You've left open the possibility that one thread could set turn before the other thread's while argument is fully evaluated, causing your threads to deadlock down the road.

If you only wish to guarantee that each thread must not be inside the while loop while the other thread is, then you should instead write each of your `while` loops to look something like this:

```
while(true){
    synchronized(Main.class){
        print( ch, 4);
        count++;
        System.out.println("Counter is : " + count);
    }
}
```

If you want to guarantee that each thread must "take turns", you should look into using `wait()` and `notify()`.

Comment: after using AtomicInteger instead of primitive int, though the values of counter increment but the program halts again after some time :(

Answer (score -1):

Ok so I figured it out, the issue is that each thread needs to pause in order for the other thread to run.

Instead of just spinning the cpu using:

```
while(flag[0] && turn == 0);
```

You need to pause the thread by calling the sleep method.

```
while(flag[0] && turn == 0){
    try {
        this.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right in that each thread needs to allow the other to run, but you cannot definitively accomplish this by using sleep. It does nothing to fix the fact that `flag[0] && turn == 0` is not an atomic operation.